# Nested Attributes Links on a Static Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, hyperlink, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a nested model system and a Static Page.

My models are:

User model:

```
has_many :collections
has_many :designs, :through => :collections
```

Collection model:

```
belongs_to :user
has_many: designs
```

Designs model:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :collection
```

The static page is supposed to show ALL of every users Designs, and it does. Unfortunately, the links are broken but they are correct links I believe, I just am doing something wrong in the controller.

Here is the static pages controller for the page that shows all of the designs:

```
def home
  if signed_in?
    @designs = Design.all
  end
end
```

I've also tried to add these line (different times) before the `@designs` line:

```
@collection = Collection.all


@collection = Collection.find(params[:collection_id])
```

Here is the view for the static pages (the form at least):

```
<% @designs.each do |design| %>
  <fields are here>
<% end %>
```

Why are the links broken? As mentioned, everything looks great on the page except for the links.

To show a design:

```
link_to collection_design_path(@collection, design)
```

but this turns into:

```
myURL/collections//designs/:id
```

It should look like:

```
myURL/collections/:id/designs/:id
```

The first id is the `collection_id` and the second id is the `design_id`:

---

EDIT:

The collection id is not being used in the links.

Comment: is `@collection` persisted yet?

Comment: I have a before_action on the static_pages_controller thats finds the Collection based on the collection_id params

Comment: if i add this to the home method `@collection = Collection.find(params[:collection_id])` before the `@designs` variable then i get the error `Couldn't find Collection without an ID`

Comment: if you change your prepend `@collection.save! ;`, with the `;` on your `link_to` line, is the link created correctly?

Comment: You should write params explicitly try this `link_to collection_design_path(collection_id: @collection.id, id: design.id)`

Comment: Sorry, I didnt' follow that commment

Comment: The links I have work everywhere else on the site except for that static_page...

Comment: If you add `@collection = Collection.find(params[:collection_id])` to `home` method and get the error, it says the params[:collection_id] is wrong ,may be it's null or wrong id, could you check the backtrace of the home action and check the params?